# For-Each aggregation on a single HashtBable returns an array of HashTable[]

Tags: powershell

I'd like to scan the `src/` directory for all `.pdb` files but deduplicate them by their names (since a file of the same name might appear multiple times in various subdirectories). I thought something like this would do it.

```
$x = ls .\src\ -Recurse -Include *.pdb | 
     % { $a[$_.Name] = $_; $a } -Begin { $a = @{} }
```

And it sort of does but surprisingly `$x.GetType()` is `Object[]` not `Hashtable`. Instead, each of the items in the `Object[]` array seems to be a `Hashtable`.

I really don't understand why this is happening, it seems like `$x` should be a `Hashtable`

Comment: Its odd. Let me check it

Comment: Can you share me a sample folder structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing back `$a` once for each file. The `ForEach-Object` loop has 3 parts, the `-Begin`, `-Process`, and `-End`. The `-Begin` and `-End` parts happen once, and the `-Process` scriptblock happens once for each item passed to it.

What you need to do is move where you pass `$a` from the `-Process` block to the `-End` block. This way you create the empty hashtable in `-Begin`, you populate it in `-Process`, and then—once you have everything in it—you pass it along in `-End`.

```
$x = ls .\src\ -Recurse -Include *.pdb | 
     % -Begin { $a = @{} } -Process { $a[$_.Name] = $_ } -End { $a }
```

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: Yup, thats the perfect justification for the reason . Appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got the thing. Let me know if it helps your understanding. 
While iterating you are basically initiating **$a**.

If you see `$a.GetType()`, its a *hashtable* with a basetype as an *Object*
[image]

So, `$x.getType()` is actually holding an array of *basetype System.Objects*

[image]

That's why you are getting *Object Array* in $x inside which each one is an Object type Hashtable (as $a).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I'm saying - why is that the case?  It looks like I"m getting 153 hashtables each one with a single key/value - but my understanding is that this would give me a single hashtable since `-Begin` should only run at the beginning of the stream and it should be accumulated from there..

Comment: TheMadTechnician gave the reason for the each block. Thats the reason :)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: I understood it wrongly, I thought you were asking the reason for getting diff set of type.